# Concept design for a MMO java engine

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance, postgresql

We are building a HTML5 MMO that will leverage AJAX calls to a REST API written in Python for actions ( buy, sell, build, trade, send , attack).

Our second part of this project is a Java Server that updates the database with player stats every so often ( our server tick is every 5 seconds as of no because of performance)

```
Update town SET "currency" = "currency" + "currency_rate"
//each player can own an average of 100 towns and 
//we are benchmarking with 50k for right now
```

That query will update their currency according to their rate.  This query takes 2.6 seconds to update currency with 50k, but we have several other fields, metal, ceramic, food and population.

**Question** : With this technique we can only have a server tick every 3 seconds minimum. How do we solve this problem.  How do you go about updating thousands of entries constantly?

Our 2nd Solution : We load most of the towns into a Concurrent Hashmap and java will use it a a temp database and update the entire database every minute. ( API will be the Java server)

Comment: Do you want to persist the entire state of the game to database every 3 seconds??

Comment: The Idea is that a server constantly updates the players stats. I am looking for a solution on how one goes about creating a server that handlers constant updates like that.

Comment: @CrisG Multithreading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the whole DB every `n` seconds is not a good idea. RDBMS in general (and Postgres specifically) are not designed for such loads.

Try updating the field only when you need them. something like:

1. User wants to see the amount of gold.
2. System gets the `last_gold_amount` and `last_gold_updated` from DB.
3. System calculates `current_gold_amount = last_gold_amount + interest_rate * (current_time - last_gold_updated)`
4. System stores `current_gold_amount` as `last_gold_amount` and stores `last_updated`.
5. Display `current_gold_amount` to user.

Similar calculations can be performed for any "currency" you have.

Additionaly, step 4 can be performed only when user spends the currency or changes the interest rate to futher lower the load on DB.

Also, all the calculation can be hidden inside Postgres in a `VIEW` or set of stored procedures so that you can get/modify the amounth of "currency" with simple SQL queries.

Comment: Before I read your answer, we did decide on the solution you just mentioned. Though it doesn't solve our last problem, the population growth. Population grown is a non linear and we don't yet have a solution for that.  https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1uCut5PdRLDA2WN69jIrOAdnr43e2NhKtPNxJdskQiIg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @CrisG Why cant you use non linear formula for such calculation? I can not write a formula for your graph off the top of my head, but I am sure you can google or write it yourself.

Comment: We already have the equation, but its Temporal based (Delta T) so  essentially we have to run it on a server tick (which can be every 5, 10 , or 30 seconds) but it cannot be on call.